# How to get this div with floats responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I made an small html field and now I'm trying to get it responsive.
To make it clear, I made an picture how the fields should move when it's displayed on a smaller screen.
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ef1mR.png)

After figuring out a few hours I got this solution, whichs works fine on the Desktop but not on a smaller screen. The Logo is not moving to the top but remains on the left side.

Can someone help me with this?

Here is the code:

```
    <div style="background-color: orange; color: white; width: 30%; padding: 4px 4px; text-align: center; margin:0">Stackoverflow</div>
<div style="background-color: #f9f9f9; border: 2px solid orange; max-width:800px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="float: left;width: 30%; overflow: auto;"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7A3wAuudoXw8butMA-wxJdWYdUlNbWjC6EOV3iXnrUf08dwX3PA" /></div>
    <div style="float:left;width:70%">
            <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12pt; background-color:lightgreen">Some Informations
            </div>  
            <div>     
              <div style="float: left; background-color: lightblue; width:50%">
                  <ul>
                <li>Owner: Stack Exchange, Inc.</li>
                <li>Available in: Englisch, Spanisch, Russian, Portuguese ...</li>
                <li>Type of site: Knowledge markets</li>
              </ul> 
          </div>
          <div style="float: right; background-color: lightgrey; width:50%; padding:5px">
              <ul>
                <li>Website: stackoverflow.com</li>
                <li>Commercial: Yes</li>
                <li>Registration: Optional</li>
              </ul>

            <div style="float: left; width: auto; background-color:yellow">Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming.
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;text-align: center;"><a href="https://www.stockoverflow.com"> <input type="button" value="Go to the Website" /></a>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using [CSS @media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) ?

Comment: No not yet, what would be the right way to implement this @media CSS command?

Comment: Oh good lord! Inline styles and floating? Any reason you cant use a flexbox or grid layout instead or have your CSS in a file and use classes?

Comment: The inline CSS was just for illustration. The reason is, I never heard about flexbox or grid layout. What would be the better way?

Comment: @mkleber Look into the bootstrap framework, it provides this stuff out of the box. https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @bstory I thinks a Framework is a little bit too much for this small project.

Comment: what css is there to make the changes to the logo styles? I only see inline css with no media queries and it sets the width of the logo wrapper to '30%'

Comment: The 30% from the logo and 70% from the text fields are for the big screens. In mobile it should be 100% and 100% because there the text fields sould be underneath the logo. Can you maybe say me how the classes in CSS should look like to make it happen?

Comment: 1. you should extract that inine css `style = "..."` and put it in a `<style>` tag or a different file. Then look into `media queries` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

In order to change styles according to the screen resolution you can use a `media query`

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) { 
   .logo{
      width: 100%;
   }
}
```

Add classes to your elements in order to be able to target them with specific css rules:

```
<div style="float: left;width: 30%; overflow: auto;">
```

Becomes

```
<div class = "logo">
...
<style>
    .logo{
      float: left;
      width: 30%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do responsive with inline styles. Once you have your styles separate, you can you use `@media` queries to style elements based on screen size

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tab {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 4px 4px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  max-width: 800px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  text-align: center;
}
@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  .main {
    float: left;
    width: 70%
  }
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}

.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.col {
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}

.col-left {
  float: left;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.col-right {
  float: right;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding: 5px
}

.highlight {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">Stackoverflow</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="logo"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR7A3wAuudoXw8butMA-wxJdWYdUlNbWjC6EOV3iXnrUf08dwX3PA" /></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12pt; background-color:lightgreen">Some Informations
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-left">
        <ul>
          <li>Owner: Stack Exchange, Inc.</li>
          <li>Available in: Englisch, Spanisch, Russian, Portuguese ...</li>
          <li>Type of site: Knowledge markets</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-right">
        <ul>
          <li>Website: stackoverflow.com</li>
          <li>Commercial: Yes</li>
          <li>Registration: Optional</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="highlight">Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It features questions and answers on a wide range of topics in computer programming.
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;text-align: center;">
      <a href="https://www.stockoverflow.com"> <input type="button" value="Go to the Website" /></a>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.main -->
</div>
<!-- /.wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure is not that bad, even though it will be better if your style code was inside a .css file, if is that the case try it.

Anyways, in your mobile structure you have 3 main containers, I will called:

- main-container

  - *image-container*
  - *content*

Your *main-container* has *image-container* and *content* inside, but both has a villain, in your case that is ***float: left***, this thing will set everything to be on left of themselves an others objects around them.

I will suggest you to change your ***float: left*** and start to work with ***display: flex***, you can find tons of information in the internet about it, to help you to construct very polish structures that will obey to any rule that you will build to them.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, I made a solution out of your answers.
I made it with display:flex, flex-wrap:wrap and @media.

For this I seperated the whole "body of the box" into a Logo container and a text fields container (almost like before) and gave both flex attributes. In the text fields I used float (like before).

For smaller screens I changed the flex-direction to column and now it works how I wanted it.